# Multiple Condition in grep regex

Tags: html, grep

I want to use grep to search a file for all lines containing `<div`, except that I do *not* want lines between `<!--` and `-->`.

I have this regex to find the lines containing `<div`:   `^.*\<div.*$`

I have this regex to exclude the lines between `<!--` and `-->`:   `^((?!\<!--.*?--\>).)*$`   — but it doesn't work. It only matches when the comment is in a single line. How can I fix that?

How can I combine these in one grep line? Or do I have to type two greps?

Comment: I would use awk (http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/).

Comment: Don't parse HTML with Regex, it won't work! http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1682509 Use a XML/HTML parser instead, this will save you a lot of pain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` does not support multiline searches like your search for `<!-- ... -->`. This can be worked around by using various helper commands, but in your case it's not worth it. It's better to just use a more powerful language, such as sed or AWK or Perl:

```
perl -ne '$on = 1 if m/<!--/; $on = "" if m/-->/; print if !$on and m/<div/' FILE
```

---

**Edited to add:** If you also want to discount instances of `<!-- ... <div ... -->` on a single line, you can write:

```
perl -ne ' my $line = $_;
           if ($in_comment && s/.*?-->//) {
               $in_comment = "";
           }
           while (!$in_comment && s/<!--.*?(-->)?/) {
               $in_comment = 1 if $1;
           }
           print $line if !$in_comment && m/<div/
         ' FILE
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Can i use these regex in AWK. I have tried  `perl -ne '$on = "" if m/<!--/; $on = 1 if m/-->/; print if $on && `m/<div/' FILE` but in my output i seen a line with `<!--   <div ...  -->` (two tab between `<!--` and `<div`) and i dont see `<!--<div ..."  -->` how can i remove first one.

Comment: @MSK: Oh, I misunderstood what you wanted. I thought you were saying that you wanted to remove *lines* between `<!--` and `-->`; so, I didn't think your input could contain instances of `<!-- <div -->` all on one line. I'll update.